# What is a good spicy potato wedges seasoning?

Tags: spices, potatoes, mexican-cuisine

I've taken a liking to the simple potato wedge as an alternate to mash potato when preparing meat and three vege. However, I'm trying to get a recipe that consistently deliveries tasty wedges.

My current method is:

- Wash potatoes
- Chop potatoes
- place in plastic bag
- Add a little oil and spice mix*
- Shake
- Bake

* The spice mix is the part I've been having problems with.

I was using:

- 1 part salt
- 2 parts pepper
- 3 parts paprika

But this wasn't giving consistent results.

I've stuck with *Nandos Peri-peri* seasoning for a while as a safeguard, but I'd like to go back to my own spice mix.

I'm looking for spicy Mexican flavours, but using only spices/herbs, and not salts or flavour enhancers, apart from sea salt (not garlic salt or onion salt).

Any suggestions?

Comment: as you mention inconsistent results -- were you using the same type of salt, and same grind of pepper each time?

Comment: @Joe yes sir, cracked pepper, seasalt, paprika each time, the ratios only changed. One time I got a result which was just pepper and really not nice :(

Comment: Try adding **onion powder**, too. I like it a lot better than the all-dominating presence of garlic; it's softer and helps to blend your other flavors together.

Comment: @zanlok Unfortunately I can't use onion. All onion type veges are out of the menu, health reasons.

Comment: the 'really not nice' comment for pepper -- what temp are you cooking at? you might be burning the pepper which is going to throw off the flavor.

Comment: @Joe ~220 degrees Celsius for 15 - 25 minutes, til cooked through. Problem last time was there was so much pepper it was actually spicy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add cumin, chili powder and garlic powder to your salt and pepper. You might like a bit of curry powder or turmeric too, but I don't know if you'd call that a Mexican flavor.

Comment: +1: turmeric rocks fries. nice for savory/earthy flavor and happy color.

Comment: I'll try the Cumin, Chilli and Salt&Pepper. I already have those at home from our Thai Curry spice stock. :) Shall update this as the winning answer if it's nom :)

Comment: I like this one, the only thing I'd add is dried oregano.

Comment: A nice mix is salt , Malay curry powder and a touch of sugar as it basically has a bit of everything above

Answer (score 2):

I once mistakenly used ground cayenne pepper rather than paprika when frying some shrimp, and the result was a taste explosion!

I would recommend substituting half of the paprika for ground cayenne.

Comment: I don't know if I would go with half.  The initial recipe seems more cautious than that.

Comment: Agreed -- start with a pinch of cayenne and work up from there.

Comment: for a unique chili flavor instead of the more common/hearty paprika tang, 1:3 cayenne and pasilla powders work well together for a spicy/deep-rich zest

Answer (score 1):

Try a little Rosemary and Thyme, Garlic, Cajun spice.  All of those are great on potatoes!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had them with Dijon mustard as a spice, and it turned out really nice.